# socket io with react: emit from server to specific user

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I am working on a real-time private chat, using express, socket.io, react.
I want to emit a new message from the client, receive it on the server, then resend it to the right receiver using the socket id.

```
let users = [];
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("login", user => {
    if (user && users.findIndex(x => x.id === user) === -1) {
      socket.userId = user;
      users.push({ socket: socket.id, id: user, notifications: 0 });
    }
    socket.emit("login", { users });
  });

  socket.on("newMessage", data => {
    console.log("new msg received: ", data);
    users.find(x => {
      if (x.id === data.receiver) {
        socket.to(x.socket).emit("newMessage", data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

and in the client:

```
socket.on("newMessage", data => {
    console.log("new message received to client", data);
  });
```

but I didn't receive anything on the client, I can't figure out why.
NB: I am using functional components.

Comment: are you sure that the receiver client has logged in?

Comment: yes i am sure, no socket was disconnected

Comment: I mean, was the receiver's socket added into `users` list? Try checking the contents of `users` list prior to sending the message

Comment: i did it already, and it is in the users list

Comment: do you remove the user from list on client disconnect? according to your code, you only populate `users` list the very first time a user logs in, ignoring all subsequent `login` requests if the user is already in the list, so if your receiver client tried to connect one more time, and he was still in the list, his socket will not be updated

Comment: ```socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    users.find((o, i) => {
      if (o && o.id === socket.userId) {
        users.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });
  });```

Comment: this cheatsheet: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/ specifies sending message to individual socket as `io.to(${socketId}).emit("message")`, while you are using `socket.to(...)`. have you tried using `io.to(...)` ? alternatively, save socket itself in the list instead of its ID, and use `socket.emit(...)` ?

Comment: i did, and nothing changed